# The same type serialized to JSON in different format

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, signalr

I have an object which needed to be serialized

```
public class Order
{
    public decimal Amount { get; }
}
```

and another class with dictionary

```
public class Market
{
    public IDictionary<decimal, Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

In case of `Order` class, '0's in the end are removed after serialization.
Example `0.001215`. But in case of dictionary in `Market` not

```
{
    "0.00121500": {
        "amount": 0.001215
    },
    "0.00121800": {
        "amount": 0.001218
    }
}
```

That's why I have problem in JS when trying to access `Market`'s order by `Order`'s `Amount` field.

How to force convert both with the same way?

Comment: why are you looking up orders by amount this way?

Comment: I should apply the updates every second to `Orders` dictionary object in `JS` and by `key` it's faster. Like `orders[otherOrder.amount].someField = otherOrder.someField`

Comment: you should use a key, not a value.

Comment: in my case `amount` is a key

Comment: its not very unique. you could run into issues

Comment: How are you populating the Orders dictionary?

Comment: @GabrielLuci, sending by signalr to client

Comment: If you want to take control over the keys used to serialize an object to json, use strings as keys and format the keys yourself.

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this, you'll have to post some more code. I tried initializing a `Market` object with the values you have and serializing it, and it kept the 0's for me. (but I do think there is a better way to do this than storing the same value twice)

Comment: @GabrielLuci, thanks, actually I solve the problem by using strings, as Lasse recommend :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default Newtonsoft.Json library and default serialization configs, its behavior is to convert dictionary keys to strings and resolve them the same way as property names. One way to change this is to implement your own `NamingStrategy` and override its `GetDictionaryKey` method:

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy : CamelCaseNamingStrategy
{
    public CustomNamingStrategy(bool processDictionaryKeys, bool overrideSpecifiedNames) : base(
        processDictionaryKeys, overrideSpecifiedNames)
    {
    }

    public CustomNamingStrategy(bool processDictionaryKeys, bool overrideSpecifiedNames, bool processExtensionDataNames) : base(
        processDictionaryKeys, overrideSpecifiedNames, processExtensionDataNames)
    {
    }

    public CustomNamingStrategy() : base()
    {
    }

    public override string GetDictionaryKey(string key)
    {
        if (!ProcessDictionaryKeys)
        {
            return key;
        }

        if (Decimal.TryParse(key, out var result))
        {
            var str = result.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return str.Contains(".") ? str.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.') : str;
        }

        return ResolvePropertyName(key);
    }
}
```

And then register the new `NamingStrategy` in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options =>
{
    options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CustomNamingStrategy(true, true)
    };
});
```

Comment: Oh, great! Still don't test, but that's what I looking for. Will mark accepted when check it. Thanks!